Hello world in Drools 8.44.0.Final version throwing NullPointerException
I have created a Drools project by populating with HelloWorld rule, decision table and process files.
java_home is set to jdk11. When I am trying to run DroolsTest.java , it is throwing the below error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession.insert(Object)" because "kSession" is null
at com.sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:25)
The same HelloWorld is working fine with Drools 7.74 version. I have copied kmodule.xml, DroolsTest.java and Sample.drl.  Any help would be much much appreciated. Thank you.
kmodule.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="rules" packages="com.sample.rules">
        <ksession name="ksession-rules"/>
    </kbase>
    <kbase name="dtables" packages="com.sample.dtables">
        <ksession name="ksession-dtables"/>
    </kbase>
    <kbase name="process" packages="com.sample.process">
        <ksession name="ksession-process"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>

DroolsTest :
package com.sample;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

/**
 * This is a sample class to launch a rule.
 */
public class DroolsTest {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // load up the knowledge base
            KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
            System.out.println("KieServices:"+ks);
            KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
            System.out.println("kContainer:"+kContainer);
            KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
            System.out.println("kSession:"+kSession);
            // go !
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setMessage("Hello World");
            message.setStatus(Message.HELLO);
            kSession.insert(message);
            kSession.fireAllRules();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class Message {

        public static final int HELLO = 0;
        public static final int GOODBYE = 1;

        private String message;

        private int status;

        public String getMessage() {
            return this.message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return this.status;
        }

        public void setStatus(int status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

    }

}

Sample.drl:
package com.sample.rules
 
import com.sample.DroolsTest.Message;
 
rule "Hello World"
    when
        m : Message( status == Message.HELLO, myMessage : message )
    then
        System.out.println( myMessage );
        m.setMessage( "Goodbye cruel world" );
        m.setStatus( Message.GOODBYE );
        update( m );
end

rule "GoodBye"
    when
        Message( status == Message.GOODBYE, myMessage : message )
    then
        System.out.println( myMessage );
end


I tried with eclipse and code ready studio. I tried with jdk 11 and jdk 17 . no luck..

Where exactly are kmodule.xml and your DRL files located? Please share the directory structure and your build process. KieServices.Factory.get() and similar rely on these artifacts being on the classpath.

Also share your decision table, I note that you've shared DRL and not an XLSX.

kmodule is : src/main/resources/ META-INF.

kmodule is : src/main/resources/ META-INF.  DRLs are under src/main/resources in com.sample.rules package.   I have deleted the Decision table as I want to see a drl working first.

Does this answer your question? Drools Rule Engine Null Pointer Exception

I tried that already , but that was giving me a different error. So I achieved this using maven project. Thank you so much for your response.

yeah that "other error" is the correct way to go. you don't have a session named 'ksession-rules' on your container, you have it on your kbase, so you have to call newKieSession on the kbase and not the kcontainer. I'm not sure what you mean by "achieved this using maven project" since your directory structure is a maven directory structure ....

I created a maven project , added kogito maven plugin as a dependency.  This worked .

So basically you actually put the resources on your classpath. As I had said, "KieServices.Factory.get() ... rely on these artifacts being on the classpath."
